# Fuzzy search and boosting in Solr

Tags: solr, solr-search

How to fix the query

```
name:((lenovo laptop)~1)^4
```

I want to allow only one character to be wrong, and to boost this query.
I am getting the error

```
Encountered " <FUZZY_SLOP> "~1 ""
```

How to fix it?

Comment: name:(lenovo laptop OR (lenovo laptop~1)^4)....can you try this

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti same error

Comment: try using dismax or edismax parser...defType=edismax&q=black&qf=name^2.0

Comment: you can also add the phrase slop or query slop as required...https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/TestDemo2/select?defType=dismax&df=name&mm=1&q=lenovo%20laptap&qf=name^4